# How to use 'money' data type in Knex.js migration?

Tags: javascript, postgresql, knex.js

I would like to use the `money` data type in one of my Knex.js migrations.

I'm using PostgresQL which has a 'money' data type ([docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/datatype-money.html)) and I would like to use it in my table. I've tried simply calling `table.money('price')`, but I get an error saying

`TypeError: table.money is not a function`

Is there any way I can use the `money` data type using Knex.js?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'd use `numeric(12,2)` instead of `money`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With .specificType(colName, type) you can pass any type to schema builder.